# Date format change to dd/mm/yyyy to dd mon yy in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, format

I tried below query to get date format as **25 Sep 2018** but it is not converting the date type and actual date format is in `dd/mm/yyyy` format.
Please help.

```
select convert(varchar, FOUNDEDYEAR, 108)FROM EDELGIVE_KYC_DETAILSS
```

Comment: why are you storing date in string ?

Comment: Dates have no format in SQL Server; you should be storing them as the `date` data type and worrying about the format in your presentation layer.

Comment: Hi i am storing date as dd/mm/yy format

Comment: What is the datatype of the `FOUNDEDYEAR` column in the `EDELGIVE_KYC_DETAILSS` table?

Comment: CREATE TABLE [dbo].[EDELGIVE_KYC_DETAILSS](
 [KYCID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
 [NGOID] [int] NOT NULL,
 [ORGANISATIONNAME] [nvarchar](200) NULL,
 [NGO_ADDRESS] [nvarchar](700) NULL,
 [CITYID] [int] NULL,
 [PIN] [int] NULL,
 [STATEID] [int] NULL,
 [TELEPHONENUMBER] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
 [WEBSITE] [nvarchar](200) NULL,
 [SOLUTIONFOUNDER] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
 [ORG_FOUNDER_FNAME] [nvarchar](200) NULL,
 [ORG_FOUNDER_LNAME] [nvarchar](200) NULL,
 [FOUNDEDYEAR] [nvarchar](20) NULL
 
)

Comment: For the sake of future generations, start thinking about your code. Your FOUNDEDYEAR column is nvarchar - why do you believe that converting it to varchar does anything useful? It won't - and it just might accidentally corrupt your value if the unicode value contains characters that do not exist in ascii. It also will not change any formatting that might exist.Stop the laziness and convert/cast to a string of a specific length - do not assume the correct length will be used. Lastly - all columns are nullable? Nope - that is just wrong.

Comment: As others have pointed out- your `SELECT` doesn't work because you've stored the data as `nvarchar(20)` and not as the `DATE` datatype.  From an efficiency point of view, this is bad design because dd/mm/yyyy as `nvarchar` costs 20 bytes of storage- whereas a DATE datatype would only cost 3 bytes of storage.  Instead of putting a band-aid on an immediate problem, you should fix your database to use the correct datatypes.

Comment: yes agree.i have already  changed data type from nvarchar to datetime yesterday.

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT (convert(NVARCHAR, convert(datetime, '25/09/2018', 103), 106))
```

output

```
25 Sep 2018
```

Answer (score 0):

try like below

```
   SELECT (convert(NVARCHAR, getdate(), 106))
   25 Sep 2018

select (convert(NVARCHAR, FOUNDEDYEAR, 106))FROM EDELGIVE_KYC_DETAILSS
```

Comment: Hi i want the date  25/09/2018 as  25 Sep 2018.

Comment: when ever i am using    SELECT (convert(NVARCHAR, getdate(), 106)) it is giving  proper answer but whenever i am using select (convert(NVARCHAR, FOUNDEDYEAR, 106))FROM EDELGIVE_KYC_DETAILSS  it is giving 25/09/2018

Comment: @radhasingh the problem is SELECT (convert(NVARCHAR, getdate(), 106)) here we are passing getdate() it will be '25-09-2018'  format but what ever you are passing is '25/09/2018' format  that is difference for that only i asked to check my answer once it will helps you